# APN not delivered

Tags: apple-push-notifications, apn, javapns

I have 2 APNs, they share the same provider, same device token. First one is delivered, second one not.

```
payload={"aps":{"badge":0,"alert":{"action-loc-key":"View","body":"Some guy:  Hey man"},"sound":"NewMessage.caf"}} <- this one is delivered

payload={"aps":{"badge":0,"alert":{"action-loc-key":"","body":""}}} <- this one not delivered
```

I could not find any info about empty body in Apple docs.
So, why it's not delivered?

Answer (score 0):

> The payload must include an alert dictionary with title, subtitle, or body information.

Empty values are treated as missing.